# Unselectable text in HTML on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, safari

If you visit **[this](https://s3.amazonaws.com/uiwebview/contents/Page04.xhtml)** page on iOS, you will not be able to select any text.
 This page doesn't contain any javascript or selection blocking code, actually if you open it on desktop browser everything will work.

I'm trying to implement EPUB3 reader on iOS and this page was generated with WYSIWYG EPUB3 editor.

So the problem is: How can I enable selection on this page without changing it visual layout?

And really important thing is: I'm hoping for solution which can be automated. So that I can preprocess this html files before opening in my reader.

**Update:** Selection starts working only when zoomed to about 400%.

Comment: I see that every line of text on that page is its own `<div>` that is absolutely positioned. As a hypothesis, maybe desktop browsers let you select text based on source order (which works in this case), but the iPhone refuses to select absolutely positioned text for fear that the selection will be out of order compared to its look on the page. Though if that is the problem, removing the absoute positioning would take a bunch of work – you would need to not only delete the absolute-positioning CSS, but also strip out the `<div>` wrappers.

Comment: Alternatively, [this Ask MetaFilter poster](http://ask.metafilter.com/115484/Cant-select-text-why) had a problem in 2009 where text selection was disabled in all browsers due to `z-index`. Maybe the CSS `#layer4 { z-index: 14; }` is the problem. At the very least, the `z-index` is unnecessary, since the `layer4` div wraps the entire page.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane Most interesting thing is that iBooks is capable to select text in this same publication. [Here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/uiwebview/contents/Page04-3.xhtml) I've removed z-index, it didn't helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computed height of `#div8` is 0. Changing this to 100% fixes the issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a cross-browser list of styles for non-selectable text:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: moz-none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
       -o-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
```

You can also set them to select text as well:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: default;
  -webkit-user-select: text;
   -khtml-user-select: text;
     -moz-user-select: text;
      -ms-user-select: text;
       -o-user-select: text;
          user-select: text;
```

The -webkit-touch-callout property allows you to dictate what does or doesn’t happen when a user taps and holds on a link on iOS. The default value is default and tap-holding on a link brings up the link bubble dialog; by using the value of none, that bubble never comes up.

The -khtml prefix predates the -webkit prefix and provides support for Safari 2.0-

The -moz prefix is defined twice with the value none and the value -moz-none on purpose. Using -moz-none rather than none prevents elements and sub-elements from being selectable. However some older browsers like Netscape won’t recognize moz-none so it’s still necessary to define none for them.

The -o prefix isn't supported but I have come across recommendations to include it for future proofing and it doesn't hurt unless minification is critical.

Non-prefixed property should be last in line.

Comment: Text is not really non-selectable (see my edit), it just really hard to select. I think it is more layout-based problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do u try this please :

```
body {
zoom: 1;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 512px;
height: 768px;
-webkit-user-select: text; // THIS ALLOW SELECT TEXT ON IOS
}
```

-webkit-user-select, which are also value : "none", "all", "element"

Comment: Here you can try it: https://s3.amazonaws.com/uiwebview/contents/Page04-4.xhtml It didn't change anything.

Comment: Ok, then couple of questions: 1. Does [**this**](https://s3.amazonaws.com/uiwebview/contents/Page04-4.xhtml) link works on your iPad? 2. How about [**this**](https://s3.amazonaws.com/uiwebview/contents/Page04.xhtml) one? 3. What model and iOS version do you have? I've tested on 3 devices with no benefit.

Comment: The first Link work, the second Link not work AND i have the iPad 2 with the latest iOS version ! Also i've tested with my iPhone 4S /iOS latest version AND same results

Comment: I've tested one more time and here is interesting thing: Selection works only when zoomed. But it works both for first link and second one, so -webkit-user-select is not really important. If you can select text on minimum zoom level, please give me know.

Comment: Exact! Not work with zoom mini. Perhaps work with a specifical meta head html iOS ? I want this bountie or vote ;-)

Answer (score 0):

drop

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

into the head

Comment: Could you please expand (ie. use "edit") on your to explain why this would work?

Comment: Didn't helped, here is new page with this tag: https://s3.amazonaws.com/uiwebview/contents/Page04-2.xhtml